RFCTYPE_TABLE cannot be converted to type RFC_STRUCTURE_HANDLE
I'm querying SAP using C# .NET Core, using SAPNWRFC for the first time, and I'm encountering issues with querying an RFC. Essentially, I'm calling an RFC with two parameters and retrieving the result in table T_ZSDS_IH08A, but I'm getting the following error:

SAP RFC Error: RFC_CONVERSION_FAILURE with message: T_ZSDS_IH08A of type RFCTYPE_TABLE cannot be converted to type RFC_STRUCTURE_HANDLE

Below is my code to access the RFC:
SapConfig sapConfig = new SapConfig();

string connectionString = sapConfig.SapconnectionString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ambiente"].ToString());
using var connection = new SapConnection(connectionString);
try
{
    connection.Connect();

    using var someFunction = connection.CreateFunction("ZRFC_IH08");
    var result = someFunction.Invoke<SapFunctionResult>(new SapFuncionParameters
    {
        EquipmentNumber = "",
        FunctionalLocation = "",
    });

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}


Below is my return class:
public class SapFunctionResult
{
    [SapName("T_ZSDS_IH08A")]
    public object table { get; set; }

}

Using SAP NCO in the .NET Framework, I used this line of code to receive the data from the table:
IRfcTable table = function.GetTable("T_ZSDS_IH08A");

My idea is to obtain the data from the table in result.table.

In order to investigate this problem, you also need to show the interop code that maps the C# calls to the C functions of the sapnwrfc.dll. Otherwise we can't say much... The problem here seems to be, that somewhere in that interop code, the C function RfcGetStructure() is called in a place, where RfcGetTable() should have been used.
